# can any tell me how to merge complete excel sheet into google docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am new to Google apps script.
my question is that how to export one or multiple columns from google sheet to google docs using apps script that to be in single doc

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The title doesn't match the question body, it should be a summary of the question, it should never be a different question. Please [edit] the question to make it clear what is being asked. I most cases it's a good idea to show what you have tried and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take this opportunity to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13196995/daniel-h)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the many mail merge add-ons. Choose **Extensions > Add-ons > Get add-ons** and search for "mail merge" to get started. If your sheet is a Microsoft Excel file, you will have to **File > Save as Google Sheet** to use add-ons.

[AutoCrat](https://cloudlab.newvisions.org/autocrat) is a pretty decent free mail merge tool that lets you create a single text document that lays out all the rows in the sheet the way you want, or alternatively lets you create multiple documents where each document lays out data from a single row of the sheet.